# How to get .sqlite files when developing for OSx?

Tags: macos, sqlite, core-data

I am developing OSX application with core data in it. now i want to see core data's sqlite file , but i am unable to find the path. i want these sqlite file to open in sqlite browser so that i can see my actual db data. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The path of the file is determined by the application. If you used the Xcode template, the path is in the applicationDocumentsDirectory method of AppDelegate.